# PC wont boot with HD 7770

Tags: windows-7, boot, graphics-card

My PC wont boot when i use HD 7770.

PC Specs:

- CPU: i7 3960x
- MB: GA-x79-UD3 1.0
- RAM: 16GB Kingston 1600(quad 4x4GB)
- GFX: Quadro 4000(forced to use)
- GFX: HD 7770 - problematic
- PSU: CTG-750C
- HDD: Kingston SSD+WD 1TB
- OS: Windows 7 64 Ultimate

Things i tried:

1. Booting with different GPU- works with Quadro 4000 in x16 and x8 slots
2. Booting without GOU - get windows sounds but no video ofc.
3. Booting and inserting HD7770 after boot is done - yes yes i know its bad idea - didn't work
4. Reset of CMOS, BIOS, Flashed bios etc.
5. H7770 in different PC - works without an issue

When i use HD 7770 i get green light on it when i add power cable to it(pc shut down). When i power on the PC it doesn't even shot POST screen, let alone BIOS or Windows.
This GPU was used in this PC for quite a while so i am sure it's not a hardware incompatibility.

Any idea is welcome or any test/log i can provide will be done.

Comment: Never, EVER add a non-hotplug device after powering on! Any chance to test another PSU?

Comment: As i said, i know it's a bad thing but i had to make an attempt. At this moment i do not have alternative PSU.
However Quadro 4000 is using far more power than HD7770. Shouldn't it be enough for HD7770 if it's enough for Quadro 4000?

Comment: you are probably right. I was thinking about a cable being faulty. are you using the very same cable to power these cards?

Comment: I have two cables(modular PSU) and i tried both cables in both places. No change there.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding to the question since I had the same isues on a Asus M478 LT-M, Phenom II X4, 4GB DDR3 Kngston RAM, a 600W PSU and the HD 7770. So mostly people said it's the PSU that fried my MB so I got most of parts anew. Used MSI ZH77 MB, used i7 3770 and new corsair 450W PSU with 80+ certificate and at first the new build worked for some time and than the display just turned off.
Now yet again if the HD 7770 is inside not even BIOS will load. And ofc with the new components formatted and got new Win10, which I actually did on the HD 7770 while it was working in the "fairly" new build.

Comment: how does this answer the question?